# MovieClip did not play animation when using addChild()

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, movieclip, addchild

i am trying to make a simple flash game.

And I've been searching about this problem but I can't found any questions/answers that helped me, so here it is:

I am trying to use `addChild()` to generate the pokemon Movieclips

```
    var comPkm:MovieClip = new bulbasaur;
    comPkm.x = 620;
    comPkm.y = 270;
    comPkm.height = 80;
    comPkm.width = 77;
    addChild(comPkm);
    comPkm.gotoAndPlay("idle");
```

the problem is: The "idle" stance for the pokemon does not play at all.
But, if I put the pokemon directly to the timeline it would work.
Any idea what's wrong and what's the solution?  Thanks :)

Comment: comPkm.gotoAndPlay("idle"); is this the class name of the document, or is idel on the time or is idle inside a movieclip on the main stage in the timeline

Comment: comPkm = instance name;
"idle" is the label for frame 1.  Inside frame 1, there is another movieclip that moves.

Comment: `comPkm.gotoAndStop("idle")`?

Comment: Not working, already tried both.  Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, setting some properties of a MovieClip causes the clip to not play an animation.  Setting x, y, height, or width break a timeline animation.  The silent failure without so much as a trace message confounded me several times.  A workaround is create a parent placeholder and have the ActionScript modify parent or child.  Example:

```
comPkm.parent.x = 620;
comPkm.parent.y = 270;
comPkm.parent.height = 80;
comPkm.parent.width = 77;
```

Related:  [Scaling onstage MovieClip w/ "scaleX" breaks timeline animation ...really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669763/scaling-onstage-movieclip-w-scalex-breaks-timeline-animation-really)

> If you modify any of the following properties of a MovieClip object that contains a motion tween, the playhead is stopped in that MovieClip object: alpha, blendMode, filters, height, opaqueBackground, rotation, scaleX, scaleY, scale9Grid, scrollRect, transform, visible, width, x, or y. However, it does not stop the playhead in any child MovieClip objects of that MovieClip object.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

In my experience, the playhead is permanently broken, ignoring future calls to gotoAndPlay.